# RLE 32-bit BMP, помощь с программной генерацией файла

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Сначала генерировал 32-bit bmp файлы без сжатия разрешения 1920*1080. Но понадобилось экономить память, решил применить сжатие rle для bmp. Внес изменения в header, применил правила rle. Но везде пишет, что происходит ошибка чтения формата. Вроде все уже перепроверил, помогите пожалуйста.

```
char rle_mas[1920*1080*4];   
const int rle_width = 1;
const int rle_height = 1;
BOOL rle_frame(const TCHAR* filename){
    DWORD p_row = rle_width*4; // байт в ряду
    DWORD size  = 4;
    // формируем файловый заголовок
    BITMAPFILEHEADER  hdr;
    ZeroMemory(&hdr, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    hdr.bfType    = 0x4D42;
    hdr.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    hdr.bfSize    = hdr.bfOffBits + size;

    // заголовок описателя растра
    BITMAPINFO dib;
    ZeroMemory(&dib, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    dib.bmiHeader.biSize        = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    dib.bmiHeader.biBitCount  = 32;
    dib.bmiHeader.biCompression  = BI_RLE8;
    dib.bmiHeader.biPlanes  = 1u;
    dib.bmiHeader.biWidth   = (long)rle_width;
    dib.bmiHeader.biHeight  = (long)/*-*/rle_height;
    dib.bmiHeader.biSizeImage   = 4;
    dib.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 11811L;
    dib.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 11811L;
    dib.bmiHeader.biClrImportant  = 0uL;
    dib.bmiHeader.biClrUsed  = 0uL;

    // далее запись в файл
    HANDLE fp = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, 
                                   CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if(fp == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
           return FALSE;

    // записываем заголовки...
    DWORD  dwr = 0uL;
    WriteFile(fp, (LPCVOID)&hdr, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwr, NULL);
    WriteFile(fp, (LPCVOID)&dib.bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwr, NULL);
    // output
    int step = -1;
    rle_mas[++step]=4;
    rle_mas[++step] = 0;

    rle_mas[++step] = 0;
    rle_mas[++step] = 1;

    WriteFile(fp, (LPCVOID)&rle_mas, ++step, &dwr, NULL);

   FlushFileBuffers(fp);
   CloseHandle(fp);
   return TRUE;
}
```

Выдаваемые ошибки:
Приложение "Фотографии" Windows 10: "Похоже, формат этого файла не поддерживается". 
Paint dot net пишет так: "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): В GDI+ возникла ошибка общего вида. в System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData) в PaintDotNet.Data.BmpFileType.OnLoad(Stream input) в D:\src\pdn\src\PaintDotNet\Data\BmpFileType.cs:строка 95 в PaintDotNet.FileType.Load(Stream input) в D:\src\pdn\src\Data\FileType.cs:строка 496
в PaintDotNet.Functional.Func.Eval[T1,TRet](Func`2 f, T1 arg1) в D:\src\pdn\src\Base\Functional\Func.cs:строка 158"

Comment: Добавьте конкретный текст ошибки.

Comment: Добавьте это в ответ, не в комментарии. Кнопка править и разместите.

Comment: `BI_RLE8` - это формат для (индексированного) 8bpp битмапа, а 32bpp в него не влезет. Сохраняйте в png посредством WIC

Comment: спасибо большое, мой косяк, невнимательно прочитал статью на вики.